# Xamarin Forms - SelectionChangedCommand not firing for CollectionView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

The code below shows a simple example of a CollectionView.  I am not receiving the event for the SelectionChangedCommand.  Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

btw, the complete source for this can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/JohnLivermore/XamarinFormsControlDemo).

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlDemo"
                 x:Class="ControlDemo.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView SelectionMode ="Single"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedTagChanged}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPageModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        Tags = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
        base.Init(initData);
    }

    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }

    public Command SelectedTagChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use your code and created a demo on my side, I add the `widthRequest` and `HeightRequest` to make the collectionView work:

```
 <CollectionView            
              HeightRequest="170" 
              WidthRequest="200"                        
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedTagChangedCommand}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"      
         >
```

The `SelectionChangedCommand` did triggered  after I click different items in the CollectionView.

I uploaded a sample here and you can check it: [collectionView-selectItemChanged-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/collection-selectItemChaneg-xamarin.forms)

Answer (score 13):

Couple of things that worked at my side (additionally to the `SelectionMode = Single`):

- Make sure your Command' signature is `<object>` at your PageModel and do any cast according to your needs (specially if your collection becomes more complex).
- Also at your XAML you want to give your CollectionView a name and use the SelectedItem property.
  `SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference cvTagsCollectionView}}"`

Answer (score 3):

I improved Fabricio P. answer in this way:

- Used {RelativeSource Self} for SelectionChangedCommandParameter. It helps to omit named collection views.

So your xaml part will be something like this:

```
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectObjectCommand}"
    SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

And in your view model:

```
public ICommand SelectObjectCommand => new Command<string>(i => { Debug.WriteLine("Selected: " + i); });
public IEnumerable<string> Objects { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your ViewModel, then you should use the Binding for the SelectedItem:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMonkey, Mode=TwoWay}">
    ...
</CollectionView>
```

and, in your ViewModel:

```
Monkey selectedMonkey;
    public Monkey SelectedMonkey
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedMonkey;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedMonkey != value)
            {
                selectedMonkey = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

So everytime you select a new object, the SelectedMonkey will be updated.

If you want to track the SelectionChanged, then, it should be in the code-behind (not sure how to implement within the viewmodel, nothing about that in the docs)

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">
    ...
</CollectionView>
```

And, in your Page.xaml.cs:

```
void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var previous = e.PreviousSelection;
    var current = e.CurrentSelection;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  However, I am using the FreshMVVM library which handles all the plumbing code you have above.  This is a sample project, but in my main codebase all the bindings (including ICommands) work great.  I have downloaded the CollectionView sample from the XF demo repo and am going through that to see if the problem is there as well.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you set the SelectionMode property. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection):

> By default, CollectionView selection is disabled. However, this behavior can be changed by setting the SelectionMode property value to one of the SelectionMode enumeration members:
>
> - None – indicates that items cannot be selected. This is the default value.
> - Single – indicates that a single item can be selected, with the selected item being highlighted.
> - Multiple – indicates that multiple items can be selected, with the selected items being highlighted.

Adding `SelectionMode = Single` to the CollectionView will resolve your problem.

Comment: Good catch. I added the SelectionMode=Single, but I am still not getting the event.  I updated my question with the new code and the repo.  Any other things I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Model for it  you can use the following method

My C# Model View Class

```
public class MainView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand SelectionChangedCommands => new Command<GroupableItemsView>((GroupableItemsView query) =>
    { 
        GO_Account test = query.SelectedItem as GO_Account; 
    });

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
    
}
```

And this is my XAML

```
<CollectionView  x:Name="myAccounts" 
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" 
    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommands}"
    SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference myAccountsModel}}">
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the SelectionChangedCommand firing only if my Command is setted as object, like said Fabricio P.

XAML

```
<CollectionView
  x:Name="ListaGiocatoriCollectionView"
  Grid.Row="3"
  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
  Grid.RowSpan="4"
  SelectionMode="Multiple"
  ItemsSource="{Binding ListaGiocatori}"
  SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding PopolaListaGiocatoriScelti}"
  SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding .,Source={x:Reference ListaGiocatoriCollectionView}}">
```

Code

```
public ICommand PopolaListaGiocatoriScelti => new Command<object>(async (user) =>
      {
            CollectionView cw = (CollectionView)user;
            IList<object> x = cw.SelectedItems;
            ListaGiocatoriScelti = new ObservableCollection<User>();
            foreach (object item in x)
            {
                ListaGiocatoriScelti.Add((User)item);
            }
        });
```